# Can we load Multiple Records into multiple tables into mysql-DB as a single java request?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have to load multiple records in multiple tables into mysql-DB as a single request using java. (But not with executing multiple insert queries because i have nearly 1L-10L data so i can't run that many insert queries and that many requests). Help me on this atleast like an idea.

Comment: you want to "load multiple records as a single request But not with executing multiple insert queries"? do you mean to import/export tables?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is what we do. Update multiple tables in a transaction. If you are using JDBC use multiple insert statements and use batch insert with JDBC transaction management. If you are using a framework like Spring or EJB utilise framework provided transaction management so that either all your sql statements updating multiple tables suceed as a unit or all of them fail.